# What is the difference between ListView, List, ListId, ViewId

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, view

I'm trying to find the definition of `ListView, List, ListId, ViewId`. I couldn't find a clear definition on the net.

Is it possible to find these elements from the following image?

[image]

Is there also a book that can help find the definitions with examples?

---

Is the following image correctly annotated.?
We have **two lists**: `Canal2_Merlin` and `General`. Each List has a unique Identifier as shown on the right.

**canal2_Merlin** contains a folder and a file. The Folder Id which is also a list is identified by `Ekucs52ZGptPm2CRwsI20h0B9DEuBGwOW0A7qeKiY_g2bg?e=G2yZPH` and the file is identified by `EeIstP0ZidxOo5cSuTHVCNEBWW-vhV4QZ04eIOX4TnhsuA?e=fNhKUa`.
So the folder Canal2 is also a sub-list of the previous List.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**List**:

> A list is a collection of data that you can share with your team members and people who you've provided access to.

**Source**: [Introduction to lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-lists-0a1c3ace-def0-44af-b225-cfa8d92c52d7)

> A list in Microsoft 365 is a collection of data that gives you and your co-workers a flexible way to organize information.

**Source**: [What is a list in Microsoft 365?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-is-a-list-in-microsoft-365-93262a88-20ad-4edc-8410-b6909b2f59a5)

In Short, list is a table just like Excel, to store contacts. Just like a table in Excel, it contains rows and columns. Rows for data, columns for metadata. In SharePoint, this table is called a SharePoint list.

**Source**: [SharePoint lists vs. libraries](https://sharepointmaven.com/sharepoint-lists-vs-libraries/)

---

**ListId**:

List Id in SharePoint is a unique GUID of list. You can find the list GUID from list settings page.

[Finding the Id (GUID) for a SharePoint List](https://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2008/04/29/finding-the-id-guid-for-a-sharepoint-list/)

---

**List View**:

SharePoint uses views to show list or library data. Whenever a list or library is created by default at least one view got created. For a list, the default view comes as All Items and for a document library, the default view comes as All Documents.

**References**:

1. [Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9)

---

**ViewId**:

Similar to list ID, you can also get the view GUID from List settings >> **Views** section >> Click on view name >> You can see the GUID in browser URL with query string like `View=%7BFD8A386F-67C9-4B29-B5FE-3EDD63C65E6E%7D`

---

In an image you attached, you have opened the special type of list which is called as "Document Library" in SharePoint terms.

So, **Documents** is (name of) a document library where as **Tous les documents** (All Documents) is a **view**.

Comment: Ganesh. Can we also have sub-lists as illustrated in the example.

Comment: In an image you attached, you are using a SharePoint **document library** which is similar to the local drive (file explorer) of a computer where you can store multiple folders (like general & canal2_Merlin) as well as files. Also, folders can contain multiple sub-folders as well as files.